# Bigquery insert job with default service account

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-oauth, service-accounts

I had some working code to use the rest api load the files into bigquery as described
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert
During the process I was using ServiceAccountCredentials to read the private key and gendrate JWT token then finally get the OAuth token for the insert job.
Now the same process I would need to run in a docker container within the gcp. I did not find the client to do so. That was the reason I went for Rest API the first moment. Is there a way I can generate the token using the default service account's credential? How can I reach the default service account within the java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not state what service the container is running in. Some services make Application Default Credentials (ADC) available to the container via metadata server or via secrets, others do not. For those services that do not provide ADC, you will need to specify the service account key file.

For this answer, I will show you the correct method to obtain a Google OAuth Access Token. Unless you have specific technical reasons, do not create tokens from JWT.

Obtain an Access Token from service account JSON key file:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
import  com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String  sa_file = "/fullpath/serviceaccount.json";
    String  scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";

        GoogleCredentials credentials;

        try {
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(sa_file))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList(scopes));
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
            return;
        }

        try {
            AccessToken accessToken;

            accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();

            if (accessToken == null) {
                accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
            }

            if (accessToken != null) {
                System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken.getTokenValue());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If Application Default Credentails are available in your container, you can obtain credentials this way and using the above method extract the access token.

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
```

If you are running on a Google service that supports the Metadata server (Compute Engine, etc.) you can obtain the Access Token by HTTP GET Request to this endpoint:

```
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
```

You will need to include this HTTP header with the GET request:

```
Metadata-Flavor: Google
```

Comment: Thanks John. This helps a lot

Comment: One question, does it matter to run the access token  from containers that has ADC or running the code locally. The way you showed is much easier. I used to send request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to get access token. That is more complicated. That was simply because I only found that way at that time. If no restriction this code is running from container has ADC set up or places like my local machine, it will be great simplification on the process.

Comment: Your local system will not have access to the Metadata server. If you setup Application Default Credentials on your local system then you can access ADC locally. I wrote an article on ADC: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/ Read this article also: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-and-authorizing-service-account-credentials-with-the-cli/ If you browse my site, you will find lots of articles to help you understand Google Cloud.